# Transitions for below API 19

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-transitions

I see that Kitkat added scenes and transitions (something I'm learning now). It seems very easy to implement, but if my minSDKVersion is set to below 19, I need to use @SuppressLint("NewApi").

Does this mean that my app would crash for lower sdks? I'm testing on a Nexus 5 so it runs fine. If so, can I implement Scenes and Transitions for lower APIs using a certain package? And if not, how can I design similar transitions for lower APIs?

Comment: yes it will crash if you try to use an API that does not exist

Answer (score 3):

The app will crash if you attempt to use an API that does not exist. You can use third party libraries such as [Transitions Backport](https://github.com/guerwan/TransitionsBackport), which backports the transitions framework to API 14.